# Conflict with table tr:hover border and col border

Tags: css, html-table, hover, border, col

there is a conflict with style borders in a table.

Tested in Firefox 91.0.2 (64 bit)

It is said that mainly the cell borders should be styled.

It is not that there is no solution by tricking. It is rather the case that there is a conflict.

There are complex hierarchies when styling the borders. The last one takes effect.

General:

- table
- thead, tbody, tfoot
- tr, col
- th, td

Special:

- border-top, border-right
- border-bottom, border-left

The General Hierarchy prevents column-borders from being styled if cell-borders are styled. Only tricks can solve this problem. `!important` does not solve the problem.

Likewise, row-borders cannot be styled if cell-borders are styled. This is very complex when styling with `tr:hover`. Correct would be styling with `tr:hover td`. But there is also a conflict.

There is a trick.

With `border-top` and `border-bottom`:
For this only the cell-`border-top` may be styled. Because these are overwritten by the row-`border-bottom` (see hierarchy above).

For `border-left` and `border-right`:
Only the cell-`border-right` may be styled for this purpose. Because these are overwritten by the column-`border-left` (see hierarchy above).

So it is possible to solve the problem with some tricks. However, I am not looking for a trick, but for a solution to the conflict.

In the example the following should work (and at this point don't work without tricks):

- cells (`th`, `td`): `border` = `1px solid #fff`
- column 2 (`.col2`): `border-left`, `border-right` = `1px solid #000`
- row hover (`tr:hover`): `border-top`, `border-bottom` = `1px solid #000`

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: right;
  cursor: default;
}
th {
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}
th, td {
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
}
.col0 {
  background: #ddd;
}
.col2 {
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
tbody tr:hover td {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.c0 {
  background: #fff;
}
.c1 {
  background: #f8a;
}
.c2 {
  background: #b3c;
}
.c3 {
  background: #aa6;
}
.c4 {
  background: #cf9;
}
.c5 {
  background: #9dd;
}
.c6 {
  background: #0f8;
}
.c7 {
  background: #44f;
}
.c8 {
  background: #88b;
}
```

```
<table>
    <colgroup>
    <col class="col0">
    <col class="col1">
    <col class="col2">
    <col class="col3">
    <col class="col4">
  </colgroup>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>COL 1</th>
        <th>COL 2</th>
        <th>COL 3</th>
        <th>COL 4</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td class="c0"></td>
        <td class="c0"></td>
        <td class="c5">8,36</td>
        <td class="c4">15,24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td class="c1">95,35</td>
        <td class="c3">36,25</td>
        <td class="c6">45,38</td>
        <td class="c3">28,73</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td class="c2">37,25</td>
        <td class="c4">15,24</td>
        <td class="c8">41,25</td>
        <td class="c5">8,36</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td class="c7">97,64</td>
        <td class="c3">28,73</td>
        <td class="c0">36,94</td>
        <td class="c0">8,36</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>SUM</th>
        <th>---</th>
        <th>---</th>
        <th>---</th>
        <th>---</th>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d9kju4sr/1/

Comment: To me it looks like a question of 'what do we mean by border-collapse' which applies to the whole table. If you remove that then the cells' top and bottom borders get set on a hover OK- With the border-collapse set though the setting for the cell above seems to take precedence colorwise. Am I misunderstanding the problem?

Comment: @A Haworth, thanks for the hint with `collapse`. But there is no solution with `border-collapse: separate` and `border-spacing: 1px`. The problem is also not the `collapse`, but the hierarchy. Its is possible to style not only cells, but rows and cols, but than exist the problem with the hierarchy (top & botton,right & left). Only style cells is not a solution. It don't solve the problem global (rows & columns). Test it: delete the #fff boders in the example. Than it works, but no #fff border exists between the cells, only collapse. 
https://jsfiddle.net/fhaexyz7/2/
but it is not a solution.

Comment: Hi, yes I wasn't suggesting that that was a solution (that's why it's only a comment) but to show why you are getting just one border not both styled black.

Comment: @A Haworth, yes I know why, because of the hierarchy. And I also know one (several) solutions. But that's not what I'm looking for. I am rather looking for something, with which this conflict of the hierarchy could be eliminated. For example, by making `!important` work for `tr:hover` and `.col2` .... or similar.

Comment: I found an another hierarchy. This can use as a trick. Set `tr` (top, bottom) and `col` (left, right) border (default) as `inset` and by `tr:hover` and `.col2` to `solide`.
https://jsfiddle.net/fhaexyz7/3/ 
"If several have the same 'border-width' then styles are preferred in this order: 'double', 'solid', 'dashed', 'dotted', 'ridge', 'outset', 'groove', and the lowest: 'inset'."
https://www.w3.org/Style/css2-updates/WD-CSS21-20030128-diff/tables.html#border-conflict-resolution